¿Por que pantalla completa no funciona en Phone-IOS?
Estoy tratando de que este single product (abrelo solo en pantalla moviles, para pc no esta maqueteado)
https://diablito.joshanss5.sg-host.com/ui-ux-nike de loop de productos en elementor pro con woo, se visualice en pantalla completa, usando css y js como base y las secciones de elementor pro. Pero solo se coloca en pantalla completa en Android pero en Phone se queda dentro del contenedor y codigo js lo veo bien. ¿Alguna sugerencia?
Clases en css
.articulo es la clase que a dar click en ella muestra la seccion ocultar con la clase .singleview y la muestra en pantalla completa solo en android en Phone-IOS no.
"EN TODOS LOS NAVEGADORES QUE INSTALES EN PHONE APARECE EL PROBLEMA" MENOS ANDROID
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const articulos = document.querySelectorAll('.articulo');
    const singleviews = document.querySelectorAll('.singleview');
    let lastTouchTime = 0;

    articulos.forEach((articulo, index) => {
        articulo.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const singleview = singleviews[index];
            singleview.classList.add('show');
            toggleFullScreen(singleview);
        });
    });

   
    singleviews.forEach(singleview => {
        singleview.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.stopPropagation(); 
        });
    });

 
    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', function() {
        if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
            singleviews.forEach(singleview => {
                singleview.classList.remove('show');
            });
        }
    });

  
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        const now = Date.now();
        const delta = now - lastTouchTime;
        if (delta < 300 && delta > 0) {
            if (document.fullscreenElement) {
                document.exitFullscreen();
            }
        }
        lastTouchTime = now;
    });
    
    function toggleFullScreen(element) {
        if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
            element.requestFullscreen().catch(err => {
                console.error(`Error al intentar entrar en modo pantalla completa: ${err.message}`);
            });
        } else {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
    }
});

</script> 

CSS para las sección de elementor que quiero mostrar en pantalla completa
</style>

 .singleview {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

.singleview.show {
    display: block;
}

.singleview img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

</style>


A mi parecer el problema es con safari, que es algo especial con estos temas.
Si el problema tiene que ver con elementor lo ignoro.
Si estoy en lo cierto puedes probar el uso de webkit porque los métodos requestFullscreen() y exitFullscreen() a lo mejor son insuficientes para safari.
Prueba editando esta parte de tu código a ver si resuelve tu problema:
    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', function() {
        if (!document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
            singleviews.forEach(singleview => {
                singleview.classList.remove('show');
            });
        }
    });

    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        const now = Date.now();
        const delta = now - lastTouchTime;
        if (delta < 300 && delta > 0) {
            if (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
                document.exitFullscreen();
                document.webkitExitFullscreen();
            }
        }
        lastTouchTime = now;
    });

    function toggleFullScreen(element) {
        if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
            if (element.requestFullscreen) {
                element.requestFullscreen().catch(err => {
                    console.error(`Error al intentar entrar en modo pantalla completa: ${err.message}`);
                });
            } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
                element.webkitRequestFullscreen().catch(err => {
                    console.error(`Error al intentar entrar en modo pantalla completa: ${err.message}`);
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
                document.exitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
                document.webkitExitFullscreen();
            }
        }
    }

Comprueba también que se estén ejecutando los métodos que activan la pantalla completa para descartar opciones.
Si no se resuelve con esto puede que haya algo de css en algún lugar que está chocando con el tuyo, que el position:fixed no le guste a safari o incluso necesite algún otro estilo que desconozco.
De todas maneras yo evitaría el uso de la pantalla completa a no ser que sea un caso especial, porque a nivel de usuario es algo muy incómodo.
Espero que sea de utilidad.

Probare tu sugerencia y te comento. Pero tambien Muchas gracias Sanvela, pero si me olvido recalcar que el problema también ocurre en todos los navegadores que instales en Phone, no solo en Safari es extraño el caso. Alguna recomendación de no hacerlo con Pantalla completa si no con otra forma?

Te agradezco bro, pero no me llego a funcionar tampoco.

En principio tu código parece correcto, puedes probar métodos para la compatibilidad con otros navegadores como msRequestFullscreen(), aunque si con safari sigue sin funcionar no sé porqué será. También puedes emplear otros métodos como hacer una animación para que se agrande el elemento seleccionado, un popup o cualquier otra cosa del estilo porque al final la pantalla completa es bastante incómodo.
